# Rails 3 problem loading classes from lib in config/environments/development.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I'm working on upgrading a Rails 2.3.11 app to 3.0.10. I'm getting a `NameError` in my `development.rb` file, when I try to run any of the rails scripts like `rails console`, or run my unit tests.

I'm calling a class that I have defined in `lib`, but it seems that the library hasn't been loaded when `development.rb` calls the class.

I'm doing something like:

```
config.cache_store = CustomMemcachedStore.new(Memcached.new(...))
```

I have a file `lib/custom_memcached_store.rb` that declares the class

```
class CustomMemcachedStore < ActiveSupport::Cache::Store
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant CustomMemcachedStore (NameError)
    from ~/app_name/config/environments/development.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

In `application.rb`, I am already using

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib"]
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `require` the file explicitly, rather than relying on autoload.

This is because the loading of the environment config happens early on in the startup process before autoload paths are set up.

In some cases you can work with initializers to insert configuration code into a place that works, via something like:

```
initializer "my_setup", :before => "some_other_setup" do |app|
  # ...
end
```

*Unfortunately*, this is not one of those cases, as the cache is set up [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.10/railties/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb#L46), while the autoload paths are not set up until [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.10/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L156), immediately before the `boostrap_hook`.

Comment: Thanks, the require fixes it. I really appreciate you explaining why with the code from bootstrap.rb, and not just telling me to use require.

Comment: Glad to help.  I had to look it up to determine the initializer order, so we both learned something :-)